# Internet connection change in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there an event sent by Unity that notifies about internet connection changes?
Android has a BroadcastReceiver for that as detailed in this [link](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/04/android-automatically-detect-internet-connection.html).
In Unity I only found examples of manual connectivity tests, but I'm looking for something similar to Android.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, it is possible. I found a [thread](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/534873/testing-for-active-internet-connection.html) here on Unity answers.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old, most of the suggested solutions online are not really reliable nor correct. Pinging google is not allowed (By google itself) and Unity's Application.internetReachability does not always work as it was not designed for that puprose (as stated in the docs).

The proper way is to implement a technique called Captive Portal Detection, which is what all the major OS's use for their internet status detection. If implemented correctly, it can even detect when the network is restricted (hotels or airports) as it relies on HTTP requests of known content. Therefore it is far more reliable.

It is not that hard to implement. You need to make an HTTP request to a known "check page", and check whether the right content were returned.

However, if you want a complete, ready-to-use solution, you can check the asset [Eazy NetChecker](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/eazy-netchecker-reliable-internet-detection-121725) which I created for this purpose. It also has events and a custom editor. It is not free, but it is super cheap!